# Error in Puppet agent 3.8 installation on cent OS 7.5 without internet

Tags: ruby, puppet, centos7, hiera, facter

I am installing puppet agent 3.8.7 on cent OS 7.5. The OS was installed on a new VM  and it is not connected to internet. I have created a yum repo which points to pulp repository. Below are the contents of my yum repo for puppet -

```
[root@server --- ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/puppetlabs.repo
[puppetlabs-products]
name=Puppet Labs Products El 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://136.243.83.142/pulp/repos/puppetlabs-products-el6
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
       file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppet
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[puppetlabs-deps]
name=Puppet Labs Dependencies El 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://136.243.83.142/pulp/repos/puppetlabs-deps-el6/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
       file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppet
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

when I run 'yum install puppet', I get below error. I have ruby 2.0 installed but the puppet packages reuquire ruby 1.8. When I checked the puppetlabs site, they mention puppet supports ruby 2.0. So, how do I proceed now, given the fact that my server is in internal domain and not connected to internet.
Below is the error I get on executing 'yum install puppet' -

```
[root@server --- ~]# yum install puppet
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel                                                                                                                                             | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
puppetlabs-deps                                                                                                                                  | 1.8 kB  00:00:00
puppetlabs-products                                                                                                                              | 1.8 kB  00:00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package puppet.noarch 0:3.8.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: hiera >= 1.0.0 for package: puppet-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: facter >= 1:1.7.0 for package: puppet-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(selinux) for package: puppet-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-augeas for package: puppet-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby-shadow for package: puppet-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package facter.x86_64 1:2.4.6-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package hiera.noarch 0:1.3.4-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package puppet.noarch 0:3.8.7-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(selinux) for package: puppet-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch
---> Package ruby-augeas.x86_64 0:0.4.1-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(abi) = 1.8 for package: ruby-augeas-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libruby.so.1.8()(64bit) for package: ruby-augeas-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64
---> Package ruby-shadow.x86_64 1:2.2.0-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libruby.so.1.8()(64bit) for package: 1:ruby-shadow-2.2.0-2.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: puppet-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch (puppetlabs-products)
           Requires: ruby(selinux)
Error: Package: ruby-augeas-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps)
           Requires: libruby.so.1.8()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:ruby-shadow-2.2.0-2.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps)
           Requires: libruby.so.1.8()(64bit)
Error: Package: ruby-augeas-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps)
           Requires: ruby(abi) = 1.8
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: The name of your repository suggests that it contains packages for EL6, but you are trying to use them on EL7.  Sometimes that can work, but often it doesn't.  And I don't see why you would *want* to do that.

Comment: Additionally, Puppet 3 is no longer supported.  Puppet 5.5 is the current leading-edge version, and Puppet 6 is under development.  If you're setting up a new Puppet site from scratch then I advise you to go with the latest Puppet.  It has a lot of advantages.

Comment: or at the very least 4.10.x

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Thanks for your reply. My current version of puppet server is 3.8.7 and the new VM is just an addition to the existing list of VMs which already have puppet agents installed. Thats the reason for using this version. Will newer version of agent work with an older version of puppet server?

Comment: No, newer versions of the agent will not work with a version 3 Puppet server.  My recommendation to use Puppet 5 was explicitly predicated on you being in the process of setting up a new site; since that's not what you're doing, the recommendation does not apply.  But you *do* want at least to use Puppet packages for the OS you're targetting.